# Android: how to get the intent received by a service?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I'm starting a service with an intent where I put extra information.

How can I get the intent in the code of my service?

There isn't a function like `getIntent().getExtras()` in service like in activity.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Override `onStart()` -- you receive the `Intent` as a parameter.

Comment: can you give a detail explaination

Answer (score 85):

`onStart()` is deprecated now. You should use [`onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) instead.

Answer (score 5):

To pass the extras:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra(MyService.NAME, name);
...
startService(intent);
```

To retrieve the extras in the service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {  
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        String name = intent.getExtras().getString(NAME);
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```