# How to get the value in my service class which is passed from activity class?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

Here is my code to pass the value from activity class to my service class.

```
Intent i =  new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);
i.putExtra("rowId", rowId);
startactivity(i);
```

How can i get that rowId in my service class ?
Please help me

Comment: may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964969/android-how-to-get-the-intent-received-by-a-service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
     super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
     String id = intent.getStringExtra("rowId");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for this you can

```
Override onStart() -- you receive the Intent as a parameter,
```

and

```
onStart() is deprecated now. onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) should be used instead,
```

then,

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("rowId");
```

or

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String rowId;
if (extras != null) {
    rowId = extras.getString("rowId");          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put extra in Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class); 
intent.putExtra("Key", "String");
```

You get StringExtra in Service class

```
String ba;    
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ba = intent.getStringExtra("Key");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

In the `MyAlarmService.class`

in `onStartCommand` method write.

```
String rid = intent.getStringExtra("rowId", rowId);
```

you will get the answer.